# setPristine is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I got my angular form all setup and working. The values are set after calling a response to a json request. The form is succesfully populated with the json response. After that i want to 'reset' the form, as in $scope.object.$setPristine. But i get an error:

```
$scope.object.$setPristine is not a function
```

I'm using **angular 1.4.8**.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formController" class="ng-scope">
    <form name="object" ng-submit="submit()" method="post" action="" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="object_name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="object_name" name="object[name]" ng-model="object.name" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" value="Object 2c">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="object_elements">Elements</label>
            <select id="object_elements" name="object[elements][]" ng-model="object.elements" ng-options="opt.id as opt.name for opt in options | orderBy: &quot;id&quot;" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" multiple="multiple"></select></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input ng-disabled="object.$pristine" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" ng-click="submitForm()">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is my .js:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngResource"]).controller('formController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

    var url = $location.absUrl() + '/json'

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.status = response.status;
        $scope.data = response.data;
        $scope.object = response.data;
        $scope.object.$setPristine();
        $('#modal-loading').modal('hide');

    }, function (response) {
        $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
        $scope.status = response.status;
        $('#modal-loading').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite `$scope.object` with a JSON response, of course it doesn't have any functions attached to it.

```
$scope.object = response.data;
$scope.object.$setPristine();
```

This is functionally the same as:

```
$scope.object = {of_course: "this doesn't work"};
$scope.object.$setPristine();
```

You probably just need to change your `ng-model`s to reference `$scope.data` instead of `$scope.object`

```
ng-model="data.name"
```

and then not overwrite your form object.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. But why give me -1 for my question: was the question not clear? Or because it was obvious? Whats obvious for you is not obvious for me and vice versa... Anyway... i upvoted and checked your answer...

Answer (score 0):

My way is this...

```
<form name="newClntForm" id="newClnt" class="add(newClnt, newClntForm)">
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newClnt.name" placeholder="Contact Person Name" required >
</form>
```

And Controller Save Function is

```
function(newClnt, newClntForm){
    angular.copy({},newClnt);
    // newClntForm is form name
    newClntForm.$setPristine();
    newClntForm.$setUntouched();
};
```